# How do I determine which account is removed and which preserved?

Tags: support, merge-accounts

I've made repeated attempts to try and coax SO into merging the opposite way round than it has chosen. I want account A to be removed and account B to be preserved, but I always get the message:

> Thank you for confirming ownership of your accounts. The account B will be removed, and all rep and votes will be transferred to account A as a result of this merge. Please click OK to confirm.

I have tried

- Initiating the merge request from the two different accounts.
- Clicking the email confirmation links in different orders.

Does anyone know how to do this? Thanks!

Comment: Is account A older than account B? I'd guess they want to avoid the logical inconsistency of having events on an account before that account was created.

Comment: Yes account A is the older account ... so you may have the answer here as it makes perfect sense!

Comment: So, Change the name on account A to that of account B? Why is this an issue?

Comment: Cerbus - This in fact is exactly what I've done! Thanks anyway

Comment: Ah, very well :-)